# C#: Open source SMS gateway for sending Bulk SMS with multiple message body

Tags: c#, api, sms

I need a SMS gateway for sending bulk messages to different numbers with different messages to be used in C#.
Twilio was recommended but it can't send multiple text in bulk separately.

Basic Requirements:

- C# Rest API.
- two-way SMS messaging (preferring sending only)
- capacity: more than 2500-5000 SMS/day

Comment: Free SMS services are rare, and for a reason ...

Comment: isn't there any open source gateway, sharing its API or which could be used as 'on premises' ?

Comment: thanx, I have managed to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Arad SMS Platform is an open source sms gateway and a fully-equipped business SMS platform for SMS aggregators, Mobile operators, OTTs, and enterprises. The platform is a hosted, turn-key SMS trading solution. It is completely carrier neutral, intuitive to use and it doesn't require any hardware or software. With our SMS Platform, you are able to run your SMS wholesale business from A-Z, including detailed message testing, effective routing, and pricing options and built-in finances and billing system.

https://github.com/araditc/Arad.SMS.Gateway